# Lost my passphrase but have the Json (or keystore file) and know the wallet adress

Tags: passphrase

I made an account on Ether blockchain client long time ago and I lost my passphrase (actually it consists of two words which I probably know (not sure) and some additional numbers among this words that I forgot). But I have a keystore-file (UTC) and I know the external wallet adress (etherscan shows that ballance doesn't changed for 1200 days, which is good). How can I to recover my account? Maybe to brute force combinations offline, how can I do it?

I have some light knowledge in cryptography and can write a program in C/C++, maybe Python. But I don't know how to use data from UTC file and don't understand it's structure. It would be acceptable to make a program, and run it on the processor for a weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way for bruteforce - install **geth** client and try to unlock account by RPC method **personal_unlockAccount** (or it web3 ор python analog):
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["account", "password", 10],"id":1}
This can be done at a rate of approximately 1 attempt per second.

Or see in the source files of the geth - how the UTC-file is formed and develop you own decode tool.